# How to obtain image from server directory and display in Angular 14

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core-webapi

So I have a web Api method that for the moment has a hard coded value in (will go to service eventually) but for now I'm just trying to prove the concept.

We have a bunch of images held on disk and not in a DB. I need to render images from this directory onto an Angular 14 page.

For my test From the web Api I have the following method:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("getPhotos")]
public List<Photos> GetPhotos()
{
    return new List<Photos>() { new Photos { id = 1, cost=10.2d, photographer = "bill", title="photo 1", url = "C:/photos/img20230110_21490374.jpg" } };
}
```

this is returned to Angular in an object.

in my Angular App, I have the following declared:

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'safeUrl'
})
export class SafeUrlPipe implements PipeTransform {

  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }
  transform(url: string) {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url);
  }
}
```

then I use it in my page using

```
 <img src="{{ photo.url | safeUrl }}" />
```

My photo object in Angular is declared as:

```
export interface Photo {   
 id: number;   
 title: string;   
 cost: number;   
 url: string;   
 photographer: string; }
```

The image does not display, in the console, I receive an error:

> unsafe:SafeValue must use [property]=binding:
> C:/photos/img20230110_21490374.jpg (see
> https://g.co/ng/security#xss):1
> GET unsafe:SafeValue must use [property]=binding: C:/photos/img20230110_21490374.jpg (see https://g.co/ng/security
> net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME

Can anyone point me in the right direction to get this working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using absolute file path as URL, it will not work. Also you are using files that are outside of `wwwroot` directory, which also will not work.

The first step is to copy `photos` directory to `wwwroot`.

Then you have to build URLs like this:

```
    // replace "http://localhost:5001" with value from config, or from Request URL, or hardcode
    var baseUrl = new Uri("http://localhost:5001", UriKind.Absolute);

    var result = new Uri(baseUrl, "photos/img20230110_21490374.jpg").ToString();
```